# Networking OpenVPN to Multiple Networks Routing

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I am looking to connect a vpn client to vpn server, and then for that client to also offer out a vpn server. I just cant get the routing correct.

I will try to explain the end goal.

[very quick drawing of the network im thinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI5ax.png)

I would like all clients on the Server/Client side to be able to communicate to every system on the left hand side, and also for the route to go back.

Ive been doing it for hours and just cant get the routing correct.

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming `topology subnet` are used for all servers and clients. The answer may or may not apply to tap apporach.)

To route from `10.8.0.0/24` to `10.10.0.0/24`, you just need to:

1. allow IP forwarding between the two tun interfaces on `10.8.0.1/24`
2. push route for `10.10.0.0/24` to its clients to make sure the traffics would be routed into the tunnel.

It is a bit trickier to to route from `10.10.0.0/24` to `10.8.0.0/24`. Basically what you want on this side is to route via a client instead of the server. You might think that setting the desired "gateway client" as the `route-gateway` of the other clients would do. But in fact, it doesn't even matter.

To make a certain client as the gateway of a certain route (`10.8.0.0/24` in this case), what you need to do is:

1. add a "CCD" file (check out `--client-config-dir` from openvpn's manual for more details) for it, with its common name (CN) as the filename. In the file, add `iroute 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0`.
2. add `client-to-client` to the server conf of `10.10.0.1/24`.
3. add a "CCD" file named `DEFAULT`. In the file, add `push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"`.
4. add `route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0` to the server conf of `10.10.0.1/24` if you want to access `10.8.0.0/24` from it (or if you want to avoid `client-to-client`).

EDIT: `client-to-client` can be avoided if IP forwarding is also allowed between the two tun interfaces on `10.10.0.1/24`. Without `client-to-client`, `iroute` would only be applied to the server itself. In that case, traffics of the clients will be routed "internally" to `10.10.0.1/24` first and then `10.8.0.1/24` (because of the `route` and `iroute` applied to the server).

Comment: It may be worth noting that hardcoding IP with `ifconfig` in the client confs might break the setup. If static IP is necessary for any of the clients, use `ifconfig-push` in their CCD files instead.

Comment: It may also be worthing noting that, a client does not need static IP to work as a "gateway client".